# How can I show the details of a post along with its comments using Django framework?

Tags: django, django-views, django-comments

new to the Django framework and a little rusty with coding. I am currently trying to build a tech blog from the ground up and have been using Django Central tutorials as a guide. Currently, I am stuck on [this tutorial](https://djangocentral.com/creating-comments-system-with-django/#comment-2272), particularly getting my views to show both the details of the post and the comments form.

In the tutorial, the author switches from a class-based view to a function that uses `get_object_or_404()` in order to retrieve the post. I was able to switch over to this function without any error messages, yet the post detail returns blank. Returning to a class-based view solves this issue, but I would like to go with the function provided in the tutorial.

Here is the code:

**views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
template_name = 'post_detail.html'
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
new_comment = None
# Comment posted
if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():

        # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        # Assign the current post to the comment
        new_comment.post = post
        # Save the comment to the database
        new_comment.save()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()

return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                       'comments': comments,
                                       'new_comment': new_comment,
                                       'comment_form': comment_form})
```

And here is a screenshot of what a post detail looks like with this function in use:

[image: Screenshot of blog]

Comment: try printing out post and comments to your console and post the output

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have actually fixed this problem. I was trying to create a separate template for the comments. After putting together the templates comments.html and post_detail.html things seem to be working. :-)